# Cordova File API saving file to memory card

Tags: javascript, android, file, cordova, fileapi

Firstly why in gods name is there no tutorial for this even Cordova's guides don't tell you how to save a flaming file to a location on the phone.

```
(function(w){
    function FileServices(FileName, callb){
        var self = this;
        var isFileOpen = false;
        var fileHandler;

        // open file handle
        function OpenFile(callb){
            window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 5*1024, function (fs) {
                fs.root.getFile(cordova.file.externalDataDirectory+FileName, { create: true, exclusive: false }, function (fileEntry) {
                    fileHandler = fileEntry;
                    isFileOpen = true;
                    callb(self, fileHandler);
                });
            }, function(e,c){console.log(e,c);});
        }

        // write to file
        function WriteFile(fileEntry, dataObj, isAppend, callback) {
            // Create a FileWriter object for our FileEntry (log.txt).
            fileEntry.createWriter(function (fileWriter) {
                fileWriter.onerror = function (e) {
                };

                // If we are appending data to file, go to the end of the file.
                if (isAppend) {
                    try {
                        fileWriter.seek(fileWriter.length);
                    }
                    catch (e) { }
                }
                fileWriter.write(dataObj);
                callback(self, fileWriter);
            });
        }

        this.writeLine = function(txt, append, callback){
            if(isFileOpen){
                WriteFile(fileHandler, new Blob([txt], { data:'plain/text' }), append, callback);
            }
        }

        OpenFile(callb);
    };
    // add to the navigator when device ready
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){
        navigator.FileServices = function GetFileServices(FileName, callback){
            return new FileServices(FileName, callback);
        }
    });
})(window);
```

All i get is "Error Code 5 = FileError.ENCODING_ERR";

I can't work it out....

Comment: Request you to check out this link for some help - https://github.com/gandhirajan/Cordova_File_Operations

Comment: It's outdated the FileTransfer System has been removed From Cordova. @Gandhi

Comment: I could see file transfer is very much supported in cordova still and its mentioned in their official docs too - https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file-transfer/index.html Not sure how you concluded that its removed as we are still using in our app running latest cordova version

Comment: I got it from SO somewhere as i was reading about the message i got "File Transfer is not defined" from Cordova and yes i have File Plugin installed...

Comment: You gotta install file transfer plugin not just file plugin